# update user information

Tags: errors, server, updates, customization

this is my code

```
/* Update user information. */
    if ( !empty( $_POST['url'] ) ){
        update_user_meta( $current_user->id, 'user_url', esc_url( $_POST['url'] ) );
        else{
        delete_user_meta( $current_user->id, 'user_url');
        }
    if ( !empty( $_POST['twit'] ) ){
        update_user_meta( $current_user->id, 'twitter', esc_attr( $_POST['twit'] ) );
        else{
        delete_user_meta( $current_user->id, 'twitter');
        }
    if ( !empty( $_POST['face'] ) ){
        update_user_meta( $current_user->id, 'facebook', esc_attr( $_POST['face'] ) );
        else{
        delete_user_meta( $current_user->id, 'facebook');
        }
    if ( !empty( $_POST['gplus'] ) ){
        update_user_meta( $current_user->id, 'googleplus', esc_url( $_POST['gplus'] ) );
        else{
        delete_user_meta( $current_user->id, 'googleplus');
        }
    if ( !empty( $_POST['email'] ) )
        update_user_meta( $current_user->id, 'user_email', esc_attr( $_POST['email'] ) );
    if ( !empty( $_POST['first-name'] ) ){
         update_user_meta( $current_user->id, 'first_name', esc_attr( $_POST['first-name'] ) );
         else{
        delete_user_meta( $current_user->id, 'first_name');
        }
    if ( !empty( $_POST['last-name'] ) ){
        update_user_meta($current_user->id, 'last_name', esc_attr( $_POST['last-name'] ) );
        else{
        delete_user_meta( $current_user->id, 'last_name');
        }
    if ( !empty( $_POST['display_name'] ) )
        update_user_meta($current_user->id, 'display_name', esc_attr( $_POST['display_name'] ) );
    if ( !empty( $_POST['description'] ) ){
        update_user_meta( $current_user->id, 'description', esc_attr( $_POST['description'] ) );
        else{
        delete_user_meta( $current_user->id, 'description');
        }
```

but it gives me server error. it doesnt work. what is wrong with my code? thanks.

Comment: Enable `WP_DEBUG` and get your server to output errors. A server error could literally be anything, you have to tell us what the error is. Also, the context of where you're using this code might help as well.

Comment: output is this `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /srv/www/domain.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/mytheme/user_profile_update.php on line 25` and line 25 is the first else statement in the aboce code.

Comment: and here is the whole user_profile_update.php http://pastebin.com/CkUhypsi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not closing the first if tag.

```
/* Update user information. */
if ( !empty( $_POST['url'] ) ){
    update_user_meta( $current_user->id, 'user_url', esc_url( $_POST['url'] ) );
} else{
    delete_user_meta( $current_user->id, 'user_url');
}
```

Also, you should use `esc_url_raw` on a raw url and then if you're echoing into the html use `esc_url`.  You also shouldn't save `esc_attr` values.  This is to be used when echoing as an html attribute value.  Instead, try `wp_filter_kses()`.

Comment: so what should i use instead of esc_attr?

Comment: Edited my answer with a substitution for esc_attr there.

Comment: okay ill try but i have another problem now. as you understand this is a custom front-end user profile page for my wordpress theme. it is working nice. here is the template file http://pastebin.com/tEatKN34 and this is the user_update_profile.php http://pastebin.com/cNAySSuA it is working but for example if i enter a value to url input and update my profile. it saves it. ok no problem but if i try to remove the url from the input it still shows the url value that i entered previous. i think it doesnt delete the user meta. what do you think?